# Why doesnt second call crash for sess.run?

Tags: tensorflow

I feed the same feed_dict to two diffrent operations, but the second one crashes with error: "You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_tensor/TrainImage' with dtype float and shape [?,60,30,1]"

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate, 0.9).minimize(loss = loss,global_step=globalstep )  

merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
accuary_sum = tf.summary.scalar('Accuracy', accuracy)
accuary_sum_training = tf.summary.scalar('AccuaryTraining',accuracy)
```

...(open sess etc.)

```
 feed=self.feed_dict(True,self.step)
      acc,_ = sess.run([accuracy,optimizer],feed_dict=feed )  %works fine
      try:
        summary,sumacc= sess.run([merged,accuary_sum_training],feed)%doesnt work
```

error raised by : 
`tf_session.TF_Run(session, options,
                                   feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
                                   status, run_metadata)`

Answer (score 0):

You are running different operations. Presumingly the first tensors (accuracy, optimizer) do not have a dependency on the placholders whereas the later operations do (merged, accuracy_sum_training).

Comment: they all depend on inputimage. Thought about that as well. Optimize ->loss->logits->modeling(here image came to play)

Comment: Might be difficult to help you any more than that based on the information provided. If you can provide a runnable (small) example then that might help.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q8w83gcqo5a0k7w/Tensorflow.zip?dl=0

just open convolutional.py and the Network Class is the one not runing perfectly.

u just need to add test = Network()
test.train() below. 

This error just occurre sth.